# Help deciphering Neumann Value

Tags: differential-equations

Version 10 has an option for NDSolve called "NeumannValue" which is supposed to allow you to specify boundary conditions of the form $\vec{n} . (c \nabla u + \alpha u -\gamma) = g-q u$ but there is no explanation of how to enter these parameters. Note that Wolfram's site puts the vector arrow on $\vec{n}$ but does not put arrows on $\alpha$ and $\gamma$ but those quantities must be vectors for the equation to make sense.

Wolfram's web site says this:

```
no conditions specified or NeumannValue[0, pred]
```

which is what you do if $g-q u=0$.

They don't seem to say how to specify c, $\alpha$, o$\gamma$, g, q, .... The documentation doesn't make any sense to me. Can you use NeumannValue to specify, say, no-flux boundary conditions for the heat equation?

If so how do you do it? Say you want to solve the heat equation on a disk so that $\Omega = Disk[]$: $\partial_t u[x,y,t] = \nabla^2 u[x,y,t]$ for $x^2+y^2<=1$ and $n . \nabla u =0$ on $x^2+y^2=1$. ?

Comment: Sorry, not a lot of time now, but have you seen [this much more detailed discussion](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/SolvingPDEwithFEM.html)?

Comment: Do nothing? I think you don't need to use `NeumannValue`.  The parameters c, α, γ are coefficients of the PDE.  Set the RHS with `NeumannValue[g - q u, pred]`, where `pred` is used to restrict the part of the boundary on which the boundary condition applies; when `pred` is false, the value is zero.  According to [NeumannValue](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NeumannValue.html).  It makes more sense, perhaps, if you set up your basic PDE in the form `op == 0` and add `NeumannValue` to the RHS.

Comment: Thank's @Szabolcs and Michael E2. It does make more sense now. They're writing LHS of the PDE as time derivatives plus Div J and then allowing you to specify n.J on the boundary.

Comment: Good question. I also have the same puzzle. From the current ducoment, tt seems the Neumann boundary condition is based on the `weak form` of a PDE. How to obtain the so called `weak form` of an arbitrary `NDSolve` solvable PDE? Is there any document or reference book on this topic?